# JAVA, Read from a text file, print out info from the array

Tags: java, arrays

very new to Java and I have a question

I was given an text file, and asked to find the employee who earn the most, and print out their info (fName, Lname, ID)

the text file was like so:

```
Date of birth fName lName    wage hr   work emp ID  
12/03/1929    Detzk Fyshe    37   49   07036310484 
04/17/1930    Cauus Walden   38   52   63612537553
07/12/1930    Barth Harling  43   72   42101524036
07/16/1930    Bartl Barnhill 43   62   48621748867
```

I manage to find the max wage. But have no idea how to print out the info

Here my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File inFile =  new File ("dataSet.txt");
    ArrayList <String> inData = new ArrayList <String>();


    String strline;


   try
   {  
       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (fstream));
       while ((strline = br.readLine()) != null) 
       {
                    strline = strline.trim(); 
                    if ((strline.length()!=0)) inData.add(strline); 
                    }


   } catch (Exception e)    {   
                            System.err.println("Error CANNOT FIND FILE!");
                            }


       // Max wage finder *start*

    int maxWage=0;
    for (int i=0; i<inData.size(); i++){

    String [] word = inData.get(i).split(" ");
     int wage=Integer.parseInt (word[3]);
     int hrWork=Integer.parseInt (word[4]);
     int earn = wage*hrWork;

      if (earn>maxWage){
          maxWage=earn;
      }  
}
  System.out.println("Max Wage in $:"+maxWage);

//max wage finder *end*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading in employee data, then an object-oriented solution to the problem is to create an `Employee` class with strongly typed (dates as `Date`s, and integers as `int`s) attributes that model the contents of the file.

In addition to the instance variables that would store the actual data of each `Employee`, you might want to override the `toString()` method in the class so that the employee information can be easily output, for example to `System.out`. Also, you would need a getter for the "total salary" of an employee (which you calculate with `wage * hrWork`) so that the salaries of two employees can be compared externally, e.g. by a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

All in all, the code could look like this for the relevant parts:

```
private static final DateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
...
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
...
// within the loop that reads the file:
String[] columns = strline.split(" ");    
employees.add(new Employee(
                  FORMATTER.parse(columns[0]), // DOB,
                  columns[1], // first name
                  columns[2], // last name
                  Integer.parseInt(columns[3]), // wage
                  Integer.parseInt(columns[4]), // hr
                  columns[5]) // employee id
               ); 
...
// after all lines have been read, output the employee with largest wage
Employee earnsMost = Collections.max(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
      return e1.getTotalSalary() - e2.getTotalSalary();
    }
});

System.out.println(earnsMost + " earns most.");
```

Comment: wooh... Since I am still at entry level. This literately just blew my mind o.o

Comment: @duhNooby, sorry, the answer is a bit condensed as I didn't want to implement `Employee` for you -- it would be a good lesson to try it yourself. :) The main takeaway I wanted to express was that I think it really helps to start thinking object-oriented early on: Model the problem domain in classes that encapsulate the functionality that you need to use; in this case the calculation of the total salary (in the `getTotalSalary` method) and the output format of an employee (in the `toString` method). See also: [separation of concers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).